# Python split(?) an item into multiple with comma for csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following output

123399383  (blahthing1)(blahthing2)(blahthing3)(blahthing4)

I tried using replace to replace the () with a comma which worked but its still a single item and the entire line shows up in a single cell of my csv.
What I'd like is

123399383,blahthing1,blahthing2,blahthing3,blahthing4

So each is a separate cell in my csv.
Example is one of hundreds of lines I'm going through.
Thanks for the time and any help you can throw me.

Answer (score 1):

For your exact type of string, we can use `re.findall` here for a regex based approach:

```py
inp = "123399383 (blahthing1)(blahthing2)(blahthing3)(blahthing4)"
output = ','.join(re.findall(r'\w+', inp))
print(output)  # 123399383,blahthing1,blahthing2,blahthing3,blahthing4
```

Answer (score 1):

`re.split()` will let you split on the specific characters you have. This will allow non-word characters to exist in the strings:

```
import re

s = '123399383 (blah++thing1)(blaht-&^hing2)(blah  thing3)(blahthing4)'

# split on space or closing parenthesis      
# and opening parentheses   
re.split(r'[\s\)]\(', s)

# ['123399383', 'blah++thing1', 'blaht-&^hing2', 'blah  thing3', 'blahthing4)']
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to solve it using regex is;

```
original = "123399383(blahthing1)(blahthing2)(blahthing3)(blahthing4)"
new = re.sub("\W+", ",", s)[:-1]
print(new)
```